# How can I access ttf raster images with Python?

Tags: python, image, fonts, python-imaging-library

Every font has a number of glyphs, which I can see when I look in Font Book (I'm on OS X).  I was wondering if there's a way to access the raster images of glyphs from a non-unicode font.

I'm constructing a string-to-image translation dictionary in Python and rendering it using the Python Imaging Library, but I'm finding it tedious to get the images by pasting the examples in Font Book onto a Paint app and then saving those (non-raster) images.  Is there another way to do this?

Comment: What is a "non-unicode font"? For that matter, what is a "unicode font"? I ask, because there are several types of common font formats, and "unicode" is a character mapping, not a font formal. It sounds like you want to get glyph bitmaps: if you're actually dealing with OpenType fonts (like `.ttf` or `.otf`), use something like fonttools or fontforge to get a glyph's vector outline, then use any number of graphics packages to convert the vector path into a bitmap.